# Apollo GraphQL subscribeToMore not updating query data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I am making a chat app that will need to update user's query when a new message is made. I am currently trying to implement subscribeToMore, but it does not seem to be updating when a new message is made. I have checked the Apollo UI and it works, so its just on the client (code) side that doesn't work. Heres my setup:

```js
--- typedefs ---

  type Subscription {
    newMessage: Message
  }

--- resolvers ---

  Mutation: {
    postMessage: (parent, { user, content }) => {
      const newMessage = {
        id: uuid(),
        user: user,
        content: content,
      };
      messages.push(newMessage);
      pubsub.publish("NEW_MESSAGE", { newMessage: newMessage });

      // Save to database here

      return newMessage;
    },
  },
  Subscription: {
    newMessage: {
      subscribe: () => pubsub.asyncIterator(["NEW_MESSAGE"]),
    },
  },
```

And here's my component querying and displaying the data

```js
// Only placed it here for viewing convenience
const ON_NEW_MESSAGE = gql`
  subscription {
    newMessage {
      id
      user
      content
    }
  }
`
const Chat = () => {
  const { data, loading, subscribeToMore } = useQuery(QUERY_MESSAGES);

  useEffect(() => {
    subscribeToMore({
      document: ON_NEW_MESSAGE,
      updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
        if (!subscriptionData.data) return prev;
        const newMessage = subscriptionData.data.newMessage;

        return Object.assign({}, prev, {
          messages: [...prev.messages, newMessage],
        });
      },
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="p-4">
      {loading ? (
        <p>LOADING</p>
      ) : (
        <>
          {data.messages.map(({ id, user, content }) => (
            <Message key={id} user={user} message={content} />
          ))}
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And heres how my connection to the server is setup

```js
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
});

const wsLink = new GraphQLWsLink(
  createClient({
    url: "ws://localhost:4000/subscriptions",
  })
);
const splitLink = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
    return definition.kind === "OperationDefinition" && definition.kind === "subscription";
  },
  wsLink,
  httpLink
);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: splitLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Home />
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
};
```

I want to be able to get new query data and display it anytime a new message is being added to the server just like how a live chat app would.